Is it possible to read metadata from a python model before creating an instance?
I have python models which are created using a particular version of my module repository.  As updates and changes are made to the repo, the models are not always backward compatible.
I'm wondering if it's possible to store some sort of header info in the model which can be read before creating the Class instance.  This way I would be able to pull the correct repository branch that works with the previously saved model.
First, I have an ABC (Abstract Base Class), which I then build MyModel classes from.  Over time, the MyModel Class changes enough that it will not load a previous saved version.  I'd like to find an elegant solution for being able to still use that model.

Fantastic.  I hadn't considered that.  Thank you.

Except, this still requires you to load the model into its Class.  But if you don't know which version of the class that model needs how can you access the attr?

So model = joblib.load( modelfile.pym) will fail because The class needs to already be imported.  ideally it would be nice if joblib could read a header or the attributes so I could then know which version of the class module to use.

I think the question lacks some context about what you consider a "Model". I thought you were referring to a class, but apparently it's something different. I don't know what a .pym file is and whether it allows to have metadata about its contents.

Python doesn't have any notion of models; that's a concept implemented by various frameworks in Python. In any case, you probably should not be pulling code from a repository at runtime. It's certainly possible to include a header in whatever object you have to specify its version, but whatever code you need to work with a supported version should already be installed.
